# AutoSolve Tower Of Hanoi

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a function where user can autosolve the game at the current state. I got this error. Anyone who helps me is gladly appreciated.

```
    #main method
 def main(self):

    for i in range(self.iniNumTower):
        tempStack = MyStack("Tower" + str(i + 1))
        self.TowerList.append(tempStack)

    #User to choose their diffculty
    self.options = raw_input("Select your Difficulty: ")
    if self.options == "Beginner":
       self.numDisk = 3
    elif self.options == "Advance":
        self.numDisk = 6
    else:
        self.numDisk = 10

    for i in range(self.numDisk, 0, -1):
        self.endGameList.append(i)
        self.TowerList[0].push(i)
    print("[1] - Continue Steps")
    print("[2] - Auto Solve")
    print("[0=9] - Quit")
    choice = int(raw_input("Enter choice: "))
    while choice != 9:
        if choice == 0:
            break
        elif choice == 1:
            # while checkEndGame(endGameList,targetTower._data,helperTower._data) != 1:
            moveFrom = 0
            moveTo = 0



            a.printAllTowers()
            a.printTowerOptions()
            moveFrom = int(raw_input("Move from: "))
            # if(moveFrom!=9):
            moveTo = int(raw_input("Move to : "))

            if a.checkDiskMove(a.TowerList[moveFrom - 1], a.TowerList[moveTo - 1]) == 1:
                a.moveDisk(a.TowerList[moveFrom - 1], a.TowerList[moveTo - 1])
            else:
                print "Unable to move from " + a.TowerList[moveFrom - 1].name + " to " + a.TowerList[
                    moveTo - 1].name
            if a.checkEndGame() == 1:
                a.printAllTowers()
                print "You've Win!"
                print "Game End"
                break
        elif choice == 2:
           
            a.autoSolve(a.numDisk, a.TowerList[0], a.TowerList[2], a.TowerList[1])
            if a.checkEndGame() == 1:
                a.printAllTowers()
                print "You've Win!"
                print "Game End"
                break




def autoSolve(self,n, from_rod, to_rod, aux_rod):
    if n == 1:
        print "Move disk 1 from rod", from_rod.name, "to rod", to_rod.name
        cap = CurrentCapture()
        to_rod.push(from_rod.pop())
        cap.capture(self.TowerList[0], self.TowerList[2], self.TowerList[1])
        self.answerKey.append(cap)
        return

    TowerOfHanoi().autoSolve(n - 1, from_rod, aux_rod, to_rod)
    print "Move disk", n, "from rod", from_rod.name, "to rod", to_rod.name
    to_rod.push(from_rod.pop())
    TowerOfHanoi().autoSolve(n - 1, aux_rod, to_rod, from_rod)
```

This is the error I got, "IndexError: list index out of range".
Edit main method in this. I hope this helps. I am not sure why the list is out of range when i did a print out, it shows 3.

## Edit2 with traceback

traceback (most recent call last):

```
TowerOfHanoi().autoSolve(n - 1, from_rod, aux_rod, to_rod)
cap.capture(self.TowerList[0], self.TowerList[2], self.TowerList[1])
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: On which line is the error on?

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 line 6

Comment: What does self.TowerList have in it?

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 its just self.TowerList = []

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 theres also an error here "a.autoSolve(a.numDisk, a.TowerList[0], a.TowerList[2], a.TowerList[1])" if it helps.

Comment: If TowerList has nothing in it, then how can you index it?

Comment: Also, `a` doesn't seem to be defined

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 but i have aready did this 
for i in range(self.iniNumTower):
        tempStack = MyStack("Tower" + str(i + 1))
        self.TowerList.append(tempStack)

Comment: and i initialize my iniNumTower = 3

Comment: please provide a full traceback.

Comment: @johnashu added that already

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the fact that you only access a list on line 6, the error must lie there. Without more information about the code and functions in it, I can't help more than that, unfortunately!

Hope this helps.